# Jboss EAP 7.1: Strange 'jboss EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available'

Tags: ejb

I am a java EE developer, and I was trying to compile my project (which consists on three EAR projects: Service, Business and Web.

The EJB classes were in Business container. I then tried to compile using Maven 3.3.3, I also tried other versions like 3.5.3 (jboss-as-maven-plugin)

```
<groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>7.1.0.Final</version>
```

And I got this error:

```
RequestSendFailedException
org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available

2018-04-10 11:47:59,530 INFO [org.jboss.ejb.client] (default task-6) JBoss EJB Client version 4.0.9.Final-redhat-1
2018-04-10 11:47:59,623 INFO [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6:2018-04-10 11:47:59,608 [ERROR] [web.mbean.MentoTOBean] [System error, try again!]
2018-04-10 11:47:59,624 INFO [stdout] (default task-6) org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available
2018-04-10 11:47:59,624 INFO [stdout] (default task-6) at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:567)
2018-04-10 11:47:59,624 INFO [stdout] (default task-6) at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
2018-04-10 11:47:59,624 INFO [stdout] (default task-6) at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
```

I tried everything so far, and I've found that, at least, the EJB is located somehow, but the 'Bean' is null:

```
WebEJBInterceptor: InterpcetorParameters [ type: interface web.service.MentoService, name: MentoService, serverName: MentoNegocio-server, authResolverClass:WebAuthenticationResolver]. Bean Scope: null
```

My service locator is okay, as it worked before:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <tpp:serviceLocator xmlns:tpp="http://www.mento.br/ns/javaee/ejb" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mento.br/ns/javaee/ejb serviceLocator.xsd">   

    <tpp:server name="SDC">
    <tpp:initialContextFactory>org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory</tpp:initialContextFactory>
    <tpp:providerUrl>remote://localhost:4447</dtp:providerUrl>
    <tpp:user>xxxxxxxxxxx</tpp:user>
    <tpp:password>xxxxxxxxx</tpp:password>
    </tpp:server>

    <tpp:service name="MentoNegocio-server" jndiPrefix="" jndiSuffix="">
       <tpp:preserveInitialContext>true</tpp:preserveInitialContext>
    </tpp:service>
</tpp:serviceLocator>
```

I used Jboss EAP 7.1 (It worked before in EAP 6.0 but the systems now use 7.0+ due to compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in recent past and after so many analysis , I am able to find the resolution.
Here are details:
In EAP 7.1 Context Factory data is changed which was modified in 
    Provider URL :remote+http://:
    JNDI ContextFactory: org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory
Change these two in the EJB Client and issue will be resolved.

Comment: that's is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that you used an outdated jboss-client-library on the client-side which is now causing the errors?
Possibly import from your jboss-server e.g.: /app/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1.4/bin/client/jboss-client.jar into your project.

Comment: In the end the solution in my case was the one Sajid offered: By changing the properties setup from (javax.naming.Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); to (javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory"); and providing javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, String.format("%s://%s:%s", "remote", <<JBOSS_HOST>>, <<JBOSS_PORT>>));